CAN Bus Acknowledge and EOF
I am trying to connect devices (sensor + Linux computer) to a CAN bus. I see on the oscilloscope that the sensor is spamming the bus with the same frame, which, in my understanding, means the frame is not properly acknowledged.
I probed the bus for two configurations (picture below):

Computer and sensor are both connected to the bus
Only the sensor is on the bus

It is clear to me that there is a difference at the end of the frame. I expect one more dominant bit when two devices are connected due to the acknowledgment. However, this is not what's happening.
Can somebody explain what's happening here? When both devices are on the bus, is the frame acknowledged? What do the other bits represent?


Maybe different sensor data?

@SimonRichter These are not data fields but CRC, acknowledge, and EOF (as far as I understand). Even if they were data, the message from the sensor should be a ping to find other nodes, not data.

I have great difficulties to dissect the individual bits of this CAN frame. Can you translate them into a bit stream?

What's the baudrate and where's the scope time scale at? 6 consecutive bits of ones or zeroes is an error frame.
